# Writing a lockscreen for Linux?

Tags: python, linux, xorg, lockscreen

I've been looking around for a nice lockscreen to use with my XFCE system, but it seems like there are any slim lock screens around. I'm currently using `slock`, but it's just a blank screen with absolutely *no* interface whatsoever.

I'm looking to code a lockscreen in Python. I looked at the source code for `slock`, and it seems like I have to interface with Xorg somehow.

Does anybody know anything about writing lockscreens?

Comment: why not xlock or xscreensaver?

Comment: `xscreensaver` just looks awful, and it doesn't have the same "feel" as GDM or KDM. I would like to make something a bit more flexible than  it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go low-level, you can use python [xcb](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/) bindings.

If you want to use higher level bindings, you may find this [tutorial on writing a screen saver with Qt](http://qt.osdn.org.ua/screensaver.en.html) useful. Porting it to PyQt should be quite straightforward. I'm pretty sure similar resources exist for GTK.

Comment: Thanks. My lockscreen is (almost) functional. I made the window fullscreen and forced it to ignore all close signals, but you can still switch out of it via `ALT-TAB`. I'll read your tutorial, so thanks for the link!

Comment: I ended up going with the Qt4 route and just used `grabKeyboard()` and  `grabMouse()` on a fullscreen window. It works perfectly, and I have to kill my window via TTY1 in order to get my desktop back!